# Call to the CBCentralManager from another custom class

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm just pasting a code snippet, but the question is why when it calls a BLE scan from another custom class, doesn't it detect state or search? Thanks for help!

```
CustomClass.swift:

class FM: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

override init() {
    super.init()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
}

public func searchBle() {
        
    centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [TxCBUUID])
  
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [TxCBUUID])
    }    
}

ViewController2.swift:

let fm = FM()
fm.delegate = self
fm.searchBle()
```

Comment: `let fm = FM()` is maybe a local var (the snippet isn't clear), so it will be released before the delegate methods are called. Also, you might want to use a Singleton for your `FM` in other to call the same centralManager from different location in your code.

Comment: Thanks, singleton as shared works,but would like to use the protocols and delegation from the centralmanager initialization class. How to do it ? To make the new instance work in my example.